# Qual a melhor maneira de usar histogramas de projeção como características em classificadores ou NNs sem usar um resize na imagem

Tags: imagem, opencv, histograma

Estou fazendo um trabalho para reconhecimento de dígitos em displays digitais e estou querendo usar histogramas de projeção como características para algum classificador, no entanto as imagens são todas de tamanhos diferentes resultando em um numero diferente de características para cada imagem mas eu preciso de um número igual. Estou trabalhando com Opencv em C++, pensei em usar a função resize, mas isso deixaria as imagens distorcidas, gostaria de saber uma opção viável para utilização dos histogramas de projeção como características contornando esse problema.

Comment: Acredito que sua pergunta está excessivamente ampla e baseada em opiniões, saindo duplamente do escopo do site. Você pode [edit] a pergunta e elaborá-la melhor para evitar o fechamento? Pode ler [ask] para mais detalhes.

Comment: Não entendi, tenho um problema e estou perguntando alguma maneira de resolve-lo, visto que eu não tenho nenhuma ideia. Isso não está completamente dentro do escopo do site???!!!

Comment: A única coisa que você forneceu na pergunta foi o enunciado de um problema. Fazer isso faz parecer que o [pt.so] é um site de suporte técnico para resolver problemas que você não conseguiu sozinho. Por mais que fique claro qual é o seu objetivo, dificilmente uma pergunta responderá exatamente o que você procura, então será melhor se você [edit] a pergunta e apresentar mais detalhes do problema. Você pode dar exemplos de quais são as diferentes entradas do programa, como planeja utilizar os histogramas, definir qual linguagem vai utilizar, etc.

Comment: Obrigado, amigo. Pergunta editada, mais alguma sugestão?